# Deploying Chaincode Failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I was following the tutorial of hyperledger fabric "Using the Fabric Test Network", ang upon deploying the chaincode to the channel I encountered errors that I don't know what's the problem with it. I tried everything I have searched so far but no luck on fixing it. I tried uninstalling everything, and starting from the beginning of the installation but again no luck. I am new to this blockchain platform and is an aspiring developer for it. Anyone Please help.

Here is the result upon running the chaincode deployment :
[image: Image here]

Please do note that I tried installing golang (go1.13.x versions, go1.18.x and go1.19.x)but none solved the problem, anybody please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this error in your screenshot:

> go: command not found

Check you can run go from your shell:

```bash
go version
```

You likely need to add the **go** executable to your shell's PATH, as described in the [Go installation instructions](https://go.dev/doc/install).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked but, I tried this solution for more than 2 days now, and it only worked today. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows that you don't have golang on the path. You need to ensure your $PATH variable includes the directory where the go binary is installed. However a further issue is you must ensure that the correct version of Go is installed that matches the version of Hyperledger Fabric you are using. Refer to the release notes of Hyperledger Fabric found here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases for your version to determine the appropriate version of golang to use.

A simpler option would be to install the javascript chaincode rather than the Go chaincode as this doesn't require any language support to be installed

```
./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript -ccl javascript
```

Comment: Didn't think about that approach until now, thank you so much.